# Can I change String object's value passed to my method?

Tags: java, string, parameters, pass-by-reference, immutability

I found the following question [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

I read almost all of it, but could not find out yet what should I do if I want the `foo(-)` method, to change my `String`'s **value**? (maybe or not reference too, it doesn't matter to me).

```
void foo(String errorText){ 
    errorText="bla bla";
}

int main(){ 
    String error="initial"; 
    foo(error); 
    System.out.println(error);
}
```

I want to see `bla bla` on the console. Is it possible?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't change the value of `errorText` in `foo` as the method is currently declared.  Even though you are passing a reference of the String `errorText` into `foo`, Java `String`s are immutable--you can't change them.

However, you could use a `StringBuffer` (or `StringBuilder`).  These classes can be edited in your `foo` method.

```
public class Test {
    public static void foo(StringBuilder errorText){ 
        errorText.delete(0, errorText.length());
        errorText.append("bla bla");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        StringBuilder error=new StringBuilder("initial");
        foo(error); 
        System.out.println(error);
    }
}
```

Other solutions are to use a wrapper class (create a class to hold your String reference, and change the reference in `foo`), or just return the string.

Answer (score 7):

**Either use the return value of the method or create a wrapper class.**

Have it return the value:

```
String foo(String errorText){ 
    return "bla bla";
}

int main(){ 
    String error="initial"; 
    error = foo(error); 
    System.out.println(error);
}
```

Wrap the value in an object:

```
class StringWrapper {
    private String string;
    public StringWrapper(String s) {
        this.string = s;
    }
    public String getString() {
        return this.string;
    }
    public void setString(String s) {
        this.string = s;
    }
}

void foo(StringWrapper errorText){ 
    errorText.setString("bla bla");
}

int main(){ 
    StringWrapper error=new StringWrapper("initial"); 
    foo(error); 
    System.out.println(error.getString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can change this with help of reflections but its against rule.

```
void foo(String errorText) {
    try {
        final Class<String> type = String.class;
        final java.lang.reflect.Field valueField = type.getDeclaredField("value");
        valueField.setAccessible(true);
        valueField.set(errorText, "bla bla".toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String error = new String("initial");
    foo(error);
    System.out.println(error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

String values are immutable -- so once you get a value, you're stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

Literal `String`s are treated specially by the Java language; your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
void foo(String errorText){ // at this point, errorText refers to the original string
    errorText=new String("bla bla"); // now it refers to a new string
}

int main(){ 
    String error=new String("initial"); // error is a reference to the original string
    foo(error); // pass a *copy* of the reference
    System.out.println(error);
}
```

In other words, you're just pointing the local reference `errorText` at a different `String` object, which affects nothing outside the method.

More generally, though, `String`s are immutable; there's no way to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign the String reference:

```
String foo(String err) {
  return "bla blah"
}

error = foo(error);
```